# Looking for a torso piece

Tags: part-identification

I'm looking for this white torso piece here on Aladdin:

[image: torso piece here on Aladdin]

I've searched Brickset, Peeron and Bricklink for white torsos and haven't been able to find it anywhere

Does anybody recognize it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's [Torso LotR Shirt with Ornate Silver Fabric and Gold Clasps Pattern (Saruman) / White Arms / Light Nougat Hands](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb1438c01)

[image: cture]

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!!!